# Ubuntu Server, Domain And SSL

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, certbot

I connected my domain with ubuntu server. My nginx configuration of /etc/nginx/sites-available/workinglife.mdholding.uz was before the installation of ssl like this:

```
server {
    server_name workinglife.mdholding.uz;
    charset utf-8;

    root /var/www/html/crm;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    # Always serve index.html for any request
    location / {
        root /var/www/crm/public;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location ~ ^/(images/) {
        root /var/www/crm;
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/crm-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/crm-access.log;
}
```

Then i installed ssl certificate using this command:

`certbot --nginx`

I chose the workinglife.mdholding.uz and it returned, that ssl was successfully installed. I checked my nginx config and it was automatically changed to:

```
server {
    server_name workinglife.mdholding.uz;
    charset utf-8;

    root /var/www/html/crm;

    index   index.html index.htm;

    # Always serve index.html for any request
    location / {
        root /var/www/crm/public;
        try_files $uri /index.html;
    }
    location ~ ^/(images/) {
        root /var/www/crm;
        access_log off;
        error_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/crm-error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/crm-access.log;

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/workinglife.mdholding.uz/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/workinglife.mdholding.uz/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = workinglife.mdholding.uz) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot
 server_name workinglife.mdholding.uz;
    listen 161.35.200.170:80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

When i try to access my domain using HTTPS it blocks and says, that its insecure, while http still works perfectly.

My ufw is turned off:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
Status: inactive
```

Comment: When I try to connect to the https url I get a 500 internal server error. When I try to connect to the http url I can the expected 301 redirect to the https url followed by a 500 internal server error.